# Python loop.sock_accept only accepts one connection

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

My process is using `asyncio` and `socket` to communicate with other processes.  It handles one client process connection perfectly, but when a second client tries to connect, it waits forever at the client's `connect_ex` method and the server's `sock_accept` method.

The flow is this: Process #1 spawns a worker process which creates a socket server. Process #1 connects and communicates with worker process. When/if process #1 dies, process #2 tries to connect with worker process.  Process #2 can't connect.

```
# process #1 


class Communicator:

    def __init__(self, ..., port):
        ...
        self.port = port
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def connect(self):
        self.psocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, (socket.SOCK_STREAM | socket.SOCK_NONBLOCK))
        ex = 1
        while ex:
            ex = self.psocket.connect_ex(('localhost', self.port))
        self.psocket.setblocking(False)
        self.listen_task = self.loop.create_task(self.listen())
        self.emit_task = self.loop.create_task(self.emit())
        print('Connected on port', self.port)


    async def listen(self):
        ...


    async def emit(self):
        ...
```

```
# worker process

class Communicator(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, ..., port):
        ...
        self.port = port
        super().__init__()

    def set_event_loop(self):
        try:
            self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        except RuntimeError:
            self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

    def run(self):
        self.set_event_loop()
        self.psocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, (socket.SOCK_STREAM | socket.SOCK_NONBLOCK))
        self.psocket.bind(('localhost', self.port))
        self.psocket.listen()
        self.psocket.setblocking(False)
        self.accept_task = self.loop.create_task(self.accept())
        pending = asyncio.all_tasks(loop=self.loop)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*pending))

    async def accept(self):
        while True:
            connection, addr = await self.loop.sock_accept(self.psocket)
            
            self.tasks.append({
                'listener': self.loop.create_task(self.listen(connection)),
                'emitter': self.loop.create_task(self.emit(connection)),
            })


    async def listen(self, connection):
        ...

    async def emit(self, connection):
        ...
```

I know how to do this with threading, I only want to use asynchronous methods for handling multiple client connections.

Also `connect_ex` blocks when the second process tries to connects.  The first process runs through the `connect_ex` loop many times before connecting.

What's causing `connect_ex` to block and `sock_accept` to wait forever?

Comment: You are using the sockets package in an asyncio program.  A lot of the functions in that package make blocking OS calls, which do not play well with asyncio.  Asyncio has a set of nonblocking coroutine functions designed for network I/O.  Also, you haven't showed us how you launch Process 1 or how you start Process 2 in the event Process 1 dies.  That's directly related to the problem you are trying to solve, so I think it would be a good idea to show us the code for that.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Your comment helped a lot.  I replaced the normal `connect` method with the async `sock_connect` method and it works now.